# Binary relation composition (with itself)

Tags: relations, binary

To start off on the right foot. I've read: [Relations (Binary) - Composition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107988/relations-binary-composition) but I still can't really figure it out because those deal with finite sets. I have a infinite set:

$R= \{(n,n+2)|n \in \mathbb{N}\}$

Which is composed with itself. I tried applying the concept of there being one element in common in $R∘R$ such that $(x, z) \in R$ and $(z, y) \in R$. Are there multiple answers?

I figured that the composition of $R$ doesn't exist,

Because if: $x = n$ and $y = n+2$. Then $z$ must be both $n+2$ and $n$. Which is not possible.

If someone could point me in the right direction that would be awesome.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I just had a sort of revalation. Is it true that the binary relations are not linked to one another? Such that one binary relation could just as well be a few spots up in hierachy?

For example {(1,3)(2,4)(3,5)} it doesn't have to mean that (1,3) and (2,4) should be compositioned but rather any ordered pair can be used?

So that I would get RR = {(n, n+4)|n∈N}. Could I than generalize that to all compositions of a set with itself? Or does that not apply?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, regarding your revelation, sort of. That is, in this case, we have $$R\circ R = \{(n, n+4) \mid n\in \mathbb N\}$$

$$x\in \mathbb N \overset{R}{\longrightarrow} x+2 \overset{R}{\longrightarrow} (x+2)+2 = x+4\in \mathbb N$$